# can we acess post/get data using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, post, get

How can we access the variable which is submitted such as

```
<form methord='get' action='sdsd.html'>
```

using javascript?

Comment: What do you mean with javascript only? No HTML written at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values that have been "posted" with GET are now in the querystring. You could parse the querystring with JS to get the values.

Here is a general example: [Parse Querystring with JS](http://www.idealog.us/2006/06/javascript_to_p.html)

Comment: the function in the link works great, but you should add `decodeURIComponent` to `return pair[1]`, or you will get `%40` instead of `@` in the resulting string

Comment: link in you message is dead

Answer (score 7):

POST values are not accessible client side.

GET values can be accessed via

```
window.location.search
```